# Verifying Identity Server 3/4 hash in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, buffer, identityserver4

I'm trying to write out a library that mimics the validation functionality of `identity server 3` in `nodeJS` but I'm struggling to verify the buffer generated.

1. I'm not sure why but I'm getting a different length buffer completely despite following along with what I believe is the equivalent.
2. The `pbkdf2` function being run as an async task might have different behaviour over the iterations.
3. The `pbkdf2` function might be implementing a different version of sha256 or just simply isn't hmac.
4. I've screwed up the buffer management and spiting the between the salt / subkey.
5. Copy in this sense may not be working like `blockcopy` in the aforementioned exert from `identity server 3`

Though note that the hash I'm trying to verify is taken directly from `Identity Server 3` inside a separate app that was started from the `ABP boilerplate` but from my own research I don't believe they implement a custom hashing algorithm or have changed the settings. The `c#` code reference I used to convert from can be found here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/PasswordHasher.cs#L248

With some further research into the identity server 2 equivalent which uses a more mundane algorithm for checking I've noticed people reporting that they had to change the encoding, but in testing this still doesn't make it work.

Further testing using the hashpassword function contained in the class in here shows that the returned buffer is of length 61 while when verifying the decoded buffer is of size 84, sounds like some form of mismatch encoding or something where were losing bytes.

Below is my class for hashing and verifying.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
import util from 'util';

const pbkdf2Async = util.promisify(crypto.pbkdf2);

export default class HashPasswordv3 {   

    async verifyPassword(password, hashedPassword) {

        let decodedBuffer = null;

        if (hashedPassword) {
            decodedBuffer = Buffer.from(hashedPassword, 'base64');
        }

        let iteration = 10000;
        let key = decodedBuffer[0];
        let saltLength = this.readNetworkByteOrder(decodedBuffer, 9);

        if (saltLength < 128 / 8) {
            return false;
        }

        let salt = new Buffer(saltLength);

        // take the salt from the stored hash in the database.
        // we effectively overwrite the bytes here from our random buffer.
        decodedBuffer.copy(salt, 13, 0, saltLength);

        console.log(salt);

        let subkeyLength = hashedPassword.length - 13 - saltLength;

        if (subkeyLength < 128 / 8) {
            return false;
        }

        let expectedSubkey = new Buffer(subkeyLength);

        decodedBuffer.copy(expectedSubkey, 0, 13 + saltLength, expectedSubkey.length);

        console.log(expectedSubkey);

        let acutalSubkey = await pbkdf2Async(password, salt, 10000, 32, 'sha256');

        console.log(acutalSubkey);

        console.log(this.areBuffersEqual(acutalSubkey, expectedSubkey));

    }

    async hashPassword(password) {

        try {
            // Create a salt with cryptographically secure method.
            let salt = await crypto.randomBytes(16);

            let subkey = await pbkdf2Async(password, salt, 10000, 32, 'sha256');

            let outputBytes = new Buffer(13 + salt.length + subkey.length);

            // Write in the format marker
            outputBytes[0] = 0x01;

            // Write out the byte order
            this.writeNetworkByteOrder(outputBytes, 1, 1);
            this.writeNetworkByteOrder(outputBytes, 5, 10000);
            this.writeNetworkByteOrder(outputBytes, 9, salt.length);

            salt.copy(outputBytes, 13, 0, 16);
            subkey.copy(outputBytes, 13 + salt.length, 0, subkey.length);

            console.log(outputBytes.toString('base64'));


        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Writes the appropriate bytes into available slots
     * @param buffer
     * @param offset
     * @param value
     */
    writeNetworkByteOrder(buffer, offset, value) {
        buffer[offset + 0] = value >> 0;
        buffer[offset + 1] = value >> 8;
        buffer[offset + 2] = value >> 16;
        buffer[offset + 3] = value >> 24;
    }

    /**
     * Reads the bytes back out using an offset.
     * @param buffer
     * @param offset
     * @returns {number}
     */
    readNetworkByteOrder(buffer, offset) {
        return ((buffer[offset + 0]) << 24)
            | ((buffer[offset + 1]) << 16)
            | ((buffer[offset + 2]) << 8)
            | ((buffer[offset + 3]));
    }

    /**
     * Confirms if two byte arrays are equal.
     * @param a
     * @param b
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    byteArraysEqual(a, b) {
        if (Buffer.compare(a, b)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (a == null || b == null || a.Length !== b.Length) {
            return false;
        }

        let areSame = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
            areSame &= (a[i] === b[i]);
        }

        return areSame;
    }

    /**
    * Checks to see if the buffers are equal when read out from uint.
    * @param a
    * @param b
    */
    areBuffersEqual(bufA, bufB) {
        let len = bufA.length;
        if (len !== bufB.length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (bufA.readUInt8(i) !== bufB.readUInt8(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The implementation is as follows and can be used for testing:

```
import identityHasher from '../IdentityServer3/HashPasswordv3';

const hasher = new identityHasher();

let result = await hasher.verifyPassword('test', 'AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEGKKbVuUwa4Y6qIclGpTE95X6wSw0mdwhMjXMBpAnHrjrQlHngJCgeuTf52w91UruA==');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is logically correct, but has few minor issues, all of them are not related to algorithm implementation:

First

```
decodedBuffer.copy(salt, 13, 0, saltLength);
```

should be

```
// copy data from "decodedBuffer" buffer to "salt" buffer,    
// from position 13, up to position 13 + saltLength of "decodedBuffer"
// to position 0 of "salt" buffer
decodedBuffer.copy(salt, 0, 13, 13 + saltLength);
```

just because it does what you want (extracts salt from position 13 in source array), and your current version does something completely different. I suppose you messed up a bit with signature of this function.

Second

```
let subkeyLength = hashedPassword.length - 13 - saltLength;
```

You are working with buffers already, but using length of `hashedPassword`, which is base-64 string. That's incorrect (because length of base-64 string and length of byte array it represents are different) and should be:

```
let subkeyLength = decodedBuffer.length - 13 - saltLength;
```

Third

```
decodedBuffer.copy(expectedSubkey, 0, 13 + saltLength, expectedSubkey.length);
```

same story as first, should be:

```
decodedBuffer.copy(expectedSubkey, 0, 13 + saltLength, 13 + saltLength + expectedSubkey.length);
```

With this changes it will work as expected.

Comment: I thought it might be something as simple as this for the buffers, going to fix up the byte comparison and providing that works I'll accept this.

Comment: Works as intended, thank you very much for your answer.